# Что за морфема /и/ в слове "победитель"?

Tags: словообразование

По словарю Тихонова, слово победитель разбирается следующим образом:

```
побед/и/тель/
```

Попробовал найти в Интернете значение суффикса /и/ у существительных и не нашёл никакой информации.

**Вопрос:** что за морфема /и/ в слове "победитель"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"и" в слове "победитель" - это суффикс, который указывает на то, что данное слово образовано от глагола "победить", где производящая основа "победи-" плюс суффикс "-тель-"